# onchange and onclick not work consistantly

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web, scrape

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage. In this process, I need to change one of 
the dropdown of that web page. I was able to do that. But when I manually change the 
dropdown, webpage changes it's content like images and some other text. But when I do that
using VBA it doesn't do that. I tested my code several times. So if I run the program 10
times it will change the content 1 or 2 times. So I'm confused about what happening

This is the HTML of that dropdown area.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="label"><label for="pa_product">Product</label></td>
<td class="value"><select id="pa_product" name="attribute_pa_product" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_product">
<option value="">Choose an option…</option>
<option value="air-xs-2-octo-16-inch" class="attached enabled">AIR XS 2 Octo 16 Inch</option>
<option value="air-xs-2-octo-18-inch" class="attached enabled">AIR XS 2 Octo 18 Inch</option>
<option value="air-xs-2-octo-20-inch" class="attached enabled">AIR XS 2 Octo 20 Inch</option>
</select> <a class="reset_variations" href="#reset">Clear selection</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And this is the code I have developed. I think onchange and onclick work rarely.

```
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.readystate = 4

    'Body(HTML)
    'MsgBox objIE.document.getElementById("tab-description").outerHTML, , "OHTML"
    'MsgBox objIE.document.getElementById("tab-description").innerHTML, , "IHTML"
    'MsgBox objIE.document.getElementById("tab-description").innerText, , "ITex"
    WS.Range("D" & i).Value = objIE.document.getElementById("tab-description").outerHTML

    'Option 1 value
    'MsgBox objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").outerHTML
    'MsgBox objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").innerHTML
    'MsgBox objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").innerText


    objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").selectedindex = 1
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    'modify the web page for that selected item
    'For x = 1 To 5
    'objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").selectedindex = 1
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").FireEvent ("onchange")
    objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").FireEvent ("Onclick")
    objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").FireEvent ("onmousedown")
    'Next x

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    WS.Range("J" & i).Value = objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").Item(1).innerText
```

[onchange and onclick not work consistantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114914/onchange-and-onclick-not-work-consistantly)

First I used one event. But no success. So I tried using all the events I found like this.                                                                                    FireAllEvents (objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product"))                                                                                              Function FireAllEvents(ByRef objHTML)

```
Function FireAllEvents(ByRef objHTML)
With objHTML
    .FireEvent ("onblur")
    .FireEvent ("onchange")
    .FireEvent ("oncontextmenu")
    .FireEvent ("onfocus")
    .FireEvent ("oninput")
    .FireEvent ("onreset")
    '.FireEvent ("onsearch")
    .FireEvent ("onkeydown")
    .FireEvent ("onkeypress")
    .FireEvent ("onkeyup")
    .FireEvent ("onclick")
End With
End Function
```

then i called this function like this

```
    FireAllEvents (objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product"))

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    WS_Oceanic.Range("J" & i).Value = objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").Item(1).innerText
    objIE.document.getElementById("pa_product").Click
```

But it didn't work too.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there an URL you can share? Also have you introduced a long enough wait for content to update? And enough time between events? Are all those events needed?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Here is the web page. https://oceanicaus.com.au/products/oceanic-airxs-2-octopus/

Comment: What selection are you after making? And are you allowed to install 3rd party open source software i.e. selenium basic?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there official website for selenium basic?

Comment: I have included the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you need to focus and unfocus an element in order for it pick up some events, or so I have found. The code below has been working reliably for me, albeit with only a few tests.

Instead of using the selected index, you can also use the value of the option to set the select value, which is what I've done below.

```
Public Sub SOTest()
    Dim ie      As Object: Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim ele     As Object
    Const url   As String = "https://oceanicaus.com.au/products/oceanic-airxs-2-octopus"

    With ie
        .Navigate url
        .Visible = True

        Do Until .readystate = 4 And Not .busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set ele = .document.getElementByID("pa_product")

        With ele
            .Focus
            .Value = "air-xs-2-octo-16-inch"
            .fireEvent ("onChange")
            .document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Focus
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.

I checked the program. When I run the program, it doesn't work at first attempt.
But the if I run it again then it work. And I want to run this program for several urls.
So I can't use following. Because it is not always same.

`.Value = "air-xs-2-octo-16-inch"`

So I used this one.

`.Value = CStr(Replace(ie.document.getElementByID("pa_product").Item(1).innerText, " ", "-"))`

But it didn't work. And could you please tell me why you have - for all spaces.
Thank you.

Comment: You can still use the selected index approach if you prefer, just make sure to focus/unfocus and that should function. Not sure I understand your second question. The value property is being set instead of selecting the item by Index. You can find the value in the page's html. Is your question more about mapping option values to what you expect?

Comment: I asked why did you use `air-xs-2-octo-16-inch` instead of `AIR XS 2 Octo 16 Inch`
I understood from your reply that air-xs-2-octo-16-inch is in html.

And I can't understand what this following line does. Does it set focus to "Add to cart" button?
`.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Focus`

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: You likely need to provide focus to another element, I just picked one randomly. There wasn't a reason for choosing this element over another.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 0):

This is dead easy with selenium basic wrapper for VBA. After installing [selenium basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0) you add a reference to Selenium Type Library via  VBE > Tools > References

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://oceanicaus.com.au/products/oceanic-airxs-2-octopus/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .FindElementById("pa_product").AsSelect.SelectByIndex 1   'You can also use  .SelectByText

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. And I didn't know that I can control chrome from vba.What is "selenium basic"? Is it a something similar to imacro? And is there any website where I can learn about it?And is there a official site?

Comment: Selenium basic is a wrapper for vba. It allows you to automate a number of browsers with selenium (automation software) like syntax and capabilities. It is generally much more effective in scenarios like this where events need to be triggered. You can read more about it here: https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/   Tutorial here: https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/